# How to generate more than one column in a parametrable request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have to add a row to my html table but it doesn't work here's my code and muy form. 
    I want to know how to store more than one element in the modelattribute and how to use regular expressions with this request to create more than one  column? Could you help me please

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Creating database: Handing Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" ></meta>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/test}" th:object="${db}" method="post">
        <p>Database_Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{Database_Name}" /></p>
        <p>Table_Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{Table_Name}" /></p>
        <div class="form_container">

    <h3>Création de la base de données</h3>

    <table id="table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>field</th>
                <th>Size</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>null</th>

                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input id="field" type="text" name="field" maxlength="255"  required="required"/></td>

                <td><input id="Size" type="text"  name="Size" maxlength="255" required="required"/></td>
                <td><SELECT id="Type" name="Type">
        <OPTION VALUE="varchar">varchar</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="int">int</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="text">long</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="float">float</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="double">double</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="Date">Date</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="Time">Time</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="Year">Year</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="Real">Real</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="Boolean">Boolean</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="longText">longText</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="Binary">Binary</OPTION>
    </SELECT></td>

     <td><SELECT id="null" name="nullabilité">
        <OPTION VALUE="null">null</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="not null">not null</OPTION>

        </SELECT></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
 <!--    <input type="button" value="Add Row" id="add_ExpenseRow.ID" /> -->
    <div id="myDynamicTable">
<input type="button" value="Add Row" id="add" />

</div>
</div> <!-- END form_container -->

        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script>
   $("#add").click(function(){
       $('#table tbody').append('<tr><td>'+$('#field').val()+'</td><td>'+$('#Size').val()+'</td><td>'+$('#Type').val()+'</td><td>'+$('#null').val()+'</td></tr>');     
   })
   </script>
</body>
</html>




package demo;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorController;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;



@Controller
class TestController implements ErrorController{

    String login="root";
    String pwd="";


    private static final String PATH = "/error";
// En cas d'érreur
        @RequestMapping(value = PATH)
        public String error() {
            return "Error";
        }
        @Override
        public String getErrorPath() {
            return PATH;
        }
       // Afficher le formulaire de création de base de données
    @RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test(Model model){
        try {

        DetailsDatabase db=new DetailsDatabase();

        model.addAttribute("db", new DetailsDatabase());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "hello";
    }
    //Créer la base de données (submit)
      @RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String DatabaseSubmit(@ModelAttribute DetailsDatabase db, Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("db",db);

try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    // on commence par se connecter à la base factice
     String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,login,pwd);

    // on crée la base et on récupère une Connection
        Statement ps1=conn.createStatement();
        ps1.execute("CREATE DATABASE " +db.getDatabase_Name());
        ps1.close();
         url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+db.getDatabase_Name();
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,login,pwd);
        Statement ps2=conn.createStatement();
          ps2.execute("CREATE TABLE "  +db.getTable_Name() +"(" +db.getField() +" " +db.getType()+"("+db.getSize()+")" +db.getNullabilité()+");");
         ps2.close();
    // on peut finalement fermer notre Connection conn qui ne nous sers plus à rien
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();

}
return "result";
        }
public static boolean existe(Connection conn, String nomTable)
        throws SQLException{
boolean existe;
DatabaseMetaData dmd = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet tables = dmd.getTables(conn.getCatalog(),null,nomTable,null);
existe = tables.next();
tables.close();
return existe;  
}


}






package demo;

public class DetailsDatabase {

    private String Database_Name;
    private String Table_Name;
    private String  field;
    private int size;
    private String type;
   private String nullabilité;

    //private boolean Auto_Increment;
    public String getDatabase_Name() {
        return Database_Name;
    }
    public void setDatabase_Name(String database_Name) {
        Database_Name = database_Name;
    }
    public String getTable_Name() {
        return Table_Name;
    }
    public void setTable_Name(String table_Name) {
        Table_Name = table_Name;
    }
    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }
    public void setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getNullabilité() {
        return nullabilité;
    }
    public void setNullabilité(String nullabilité) {
        this.nullabilité = nullabilité;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DetailsDatabase [Database_Name=" + Database_Name
                + ", Table_Name=" + Table_Name + ", field=" + field + ", size="
                + size + ", type=" + type + ", nullabilité=" + nullabilité
                + "]";
    }



}
```

Comment: No i don't have any errors but in my form the user can enter ore than one row wich are the columns of the table i want to create but in my request i have just the possibility to generate one column

Answer (score 0):

Can you add below code in header section

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#add").click(function(){
           $('#table tbody').append('<tr><td>'+$('#field').val()+'</td><td>'+$('#Size').val()+'</td><td>'+$('#Type').val()+'</td><td>'+$('#null').val()+'</td></tr>');  
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's already added ,what i don't understand is  in the controller how to make the request "create table " generate more than one column  in dependence on how the model attributes  were created by the user .i am sorry i explain badly but i am not so good in english :/

Comment: Can you explain briefly...I can't understand

Comment: i want to fill the request create table with the  inputs of  the columns in the form example  if the user type 2 rows i should have in the request 2 columns did you understand?